# Is time dilation constant at all latitudes on a neutron star?

Tags: general-relativity, rotational-dynamics

**On Earth**, or any weakly gravitating body, total time-dilation does not depend on latitude. Earths equator is slightly less deep in Earths gravitational well but is also moving; these effects cancel:

In a rotating reference frame under Newtonian physics the centrifugal force is: $F = \omega^2 r$. Integrating this force from 0 to $r$ and adding a gravitational potential $V_g$ we get:
$V = V_g - 1/2 \omega^2r^2$.
This can be nicely expressed in terms of the absolute velocity of the reference frame:
$v=\omega r$; $V_{eff} = V_g - 1/2v^2$

We define a 1% time dilation to mean 99 seconds elapse on the surface for every 100 seconds elapsed by distant observers at rest.

Moving particles have a time dilation of $1-\tau/\tau_{inf} = 1 - 1/\gamma = 1-\sqrt {1-v^2/c^2} \approx 1/2 (v/c)^2$. The absolute error in the approximation is $~(v/c)^4$. See [this link](https://blog.cupcakephysics.com/relativity/2015/06/14/the-low-speed-limit-of-the-lorentz-factor.html) for the derivation of the approximation. Thus a particle with kinetic energy of 1% of it's rest mass has a four-momentum vector that is 1% "longer" in the time direction and a 1% time dilation.

The time dilation due to gravity is (from [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_time_dilation)) given by $1-\tau/\tau_{inf} \approx -V_g/c^2$. $V_g$ is zero at infinity and negative inside the gravity well.

For weak gravity these two sources of time dilation add:

$1-\tau/\tau_{inf} = -V_g/c^2 + 1/2v^2/c^2 = -V_{eff}/c^2$

**Hydrostatic equilibrium** means the surface of a body is at [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrostatic_equilibrium)$V_{eff}$. This is a good approximation for all bodies above a couple of hundred km in diameter. The ideal "sea-level" on Earth is a surface of constant $V_{eff}$ called the [geoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geoid).

On Earth the mantle is solid but can slowly flow, like a glacier. The solid crust, [made out of less dense minerals](https://opentextbc.ca/physicalgeology2ed/chapter/9-4-isostasy/) floats on the mantle like a [large iceberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iceberg_B-15). To make Earth more perfect we need to [melt the crust](https://www.astronomy.com/observing/what-will-happen-to-the-planets-when-the-sun-becomes-a-red-giant/). This would get rid of those pesky continents and equalize $V_{eff}$ across the entire Earth.

**A neutron star** is almost perfectly *round* but not *spherical*: the extreme gravity means they are in almost perfect equilibrium but some rotate so fast they have a large equatorial bulge. My above derivation of constant time-dilation assumed weak gravity. **But does "constant time dialation" still hold with such [considerable](https://astrobites.org/2018/11/19/what-does-a-neutron-star-actually-look-like/) relativistic effects including [frame-dragging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging)?**

My *guess* is that it does: I think it's possible to cover the star in small co-rotating reference frames which are individually nearly Newtonian. I think you can use Newtonian arguments to show that a frame covering $\epsilon$ radians of latitude has at most $O(\epsilon^2)$ variation of surface time-dilation. This would prove constant time dilation from the equator to the poles.

Comment: I want to point out: in terms of GR it is not the case that there is a velocity time dilation effect on one hand and a gravitational time dilation effect on the other hand. Treating them as different is tempting, but it isn't inherent in the phenomena. As we know: *as a matter of principle* a local measurement cannot distinguish between the two. Example: a giant cartwheel space station that is rotating so that all radial levels are pulling G's. From one level to the next there will be a difference in amount of proper time that elapses. By itself that difference does not tell you the cause.

Comment: I'm emphasizing this precisely because in the case of GR it's a matter of principle. Coming from SR it is tempting to think of gravitational time dilation as a phenomenon that can occur *concurrently* with velocity time dilation, and then it is meaningful to reason in terms of the two effects canceling each other. But the distinction is not inherent in the phenomena. There is only a single form of GR time dilation; velocity/gravitational distinction is for our convenience only.

Comment: There is a good basic introduction to the "holistic" calculations here: https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s6-06/6-06.htm

Comment: @Cleonis: That is a good point: In Newtonian physics there are natural Cartesian reference frames where the *coordinate acceleration* of a free-fall trajectory does not depend upon *velocity*. In such a frame you can separate the "velocity" vs the "gravitational" time dilation terms. But in GR this isn't the case. The Kerr metric is static but you still can't find a reference frame that zeros out either the Coriolis effect or the "spatial" curvature.